# SQL Server agent do not starts

Tags: sql-server, service, account, agent, failed-to-connect

I have an issue on one of customer servers , SQL server agent is not  being started , what I have found inside of SQL agent log is following :

```
LogDate ErrorLevel  Text
2020-02-22 22:46:48.000 3   [100] Microsoft SQLServerAgent version 11.0.7462.6 (X64 unicode retail build) : Process ID 7840
2020-02-22 22:46:48.000 3   [495] The SQL Server Agent startup service account is NT SERVICE\SQLSERVERAGENT.
2020-02-22 22:46:50.000 1   [150] SQL Server does not accept the connection (error: 808). Waiting for Sql Server to allow connections. Operation attempted was: Verify Connection On Start.
2020-02-22 22:46:50.000 1   [000] Unable to connect to server '(local)'; SQLServerAgent cannot start
2020-02-22 22:46:52.000 1   [298] SQLServer Error: 808, SSL Provider: The received certificate has expired. [SQLSTATE 08001] 
2020-02-22 22:46:52.000 1   [298] SQLServer Error: 808, Client unable to establish connection [SQLSTATE 08001] 
2020-02-22 22:46:52.000 1   [382] Logon to server '(local)' failed (DisableAgentXPs)
2020-02-22 22:46:52.000 3   [098] SQLServerAgent terminated (normally)
```

These entries are all entries that exist in log after failed sql server agent start.

services are running under standart accounts NT Service

I have tried to add these services to local administrator group

I have tried to change service account for agent to domain account - no success

what issue can be there, is anyone had faced with this previously ?

Comment: Off-topic - belongs on dba. But the first question to answer is what edition of sql server is in use? Express?

Comment: No 
Microsoft SQL Server 2012 (SP4-GDR) (KB4057116) - 11.0.7462.6 (X64) 
 Jan  5 2018 22:11:56 
 Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation
 Enterprise Edition (64-bit) on Windows NT 6.3 <X64> (Build 9600: ) (Hypervisor)

Comment: i found this content about sql server agent connectio string maybe its help you for solve your problem [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssms/agent/set-sql-server-connection-for-sql-server-agent-service-ssms?view=sql-server-ver15)

Comment: I have fixed the issue by adding new self-generated certificate and added them to SQL server engine service, after that i have changed one of the registry setting inside of SQL agent folder, registry setting "localhost" had blank value inside and I have changed this to real name of SQL Server instance, this way it use real name instead of "(local)", this way SQL agent has started and running fine! Didn't find solution of this problem in internet so maybe it help some else